What is the effect of the operator $\hat{O} = |\phi \rangle \langle \psi|$ on any state $| \psi \rangle$?
I have seen this operator in some questions,including the book Liboff,Introductory Quantum Mechanics. I am not sure how it would act on a state.

act on what state?

Please currect formating. Some characters is unreadable

Use MathJax, please.

What's wrong with $\hat{\cal O}\vert\psi\rangle=\vert\varphi\rangle\langle \psi\vert \psi \rangle$?

Maybe easier to think of the operator as a matrix acting on an appropriate column vector |ψ⟩ of the same length?

The notation and language used in this post seems to imply that $\psi$ represents both a specific state (as in $\hat O=|\phi\rangle\langle\psi|$) used to construct a specific operator, but also represents a general state "any state $|\psi\rangle$." This is confusing. Anyways, for the case of a fixed and normalized $\psi$, it is trivial to find the action of $\hat O$ on $|\psi\rangle$...

$\hat{O} = | \phi \rangle\langle\psi|$ is the operator that, when acting on any state, returns the state $| \phi \rangle$ with a weight that is equivalent to the value from the projection of said state onto the state $| \psi \rangle$
If you act with $\hat{O}$ on a state$| A\rangle$ then you have:
\begin{equation*}
\hat{O}| A\rangle = \mathcal{P}_\psi(A) | \phi\rangle
\end{equation*}
Where $\mathcal{P}_\psi(A) = \langle\psi| A\rangle$ is the projection of A onto $\psi$
